# drawing in negative coordinates java swing

Tags: java, swing, location, jpanel, jscrollpane

How can I scroll by JScrollPannel left-down to the negative coordinates area? I am developing an editor with drag and drop. For example, we have a small circle at the center of JPanel wich has a coordinates (50, 50). This circle is only drawing on the JPanel, not a java.awt.Component, thats why it can get any values of coordinates. We drag this circle left-down and its coordinates becomes (-30, 50). How can I see this circle after moving?
After dragging the circle to the right I can increase a size of my JPanel if the location of the circle will be outside of the bounds of JPannel. But what need I do to the first case?

Well, in addition I tried to draw a picture.
[image]

Comment: I don't understand what/how you want to resize... but when you resize your JPanel won't include negative coordinates. Component coordinates always start from (0,0) in the top-left corner.

Comment: Circle is not a Component (java.awt.Component), it is only a drawing on the JPanel. If you drag this circle out of JPanel it will be repainted by JPanel on negative coordinates (of course, if it will be dragging to the left).

Comment: [JPanel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html) is the Component... It's what provides the coordinate system.

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe I am not good explainer... I agree with you that JPanel is what provides the coordinate system. But have you ever tryed to draw some shape with negative coordinates on the JPanel? It works. If this shape is out of bounds only half the other half will be visible.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [Drag Layout](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2011/10/23/drag-layout/). It is a layout manager designed to allow you to drag components.

1. if a component is dragged to a negative location then the location of all components are translated by the negative amount to make sure the location of all components is positive
2. the preferred size is recalculated after each component is dragged.

Comment: Well, I thought about the same decision. Unfortunately my circles are not a Components. They are only drawings. That's why I cannot use any layouts. In any case, thanks.